# PHP Codesniffer Whitespace

Tags: php, jenkins, phpcodesniffer

have you ever met with such a problem?:

Jenkins report says that at the end of line 49 there are some white spaces but I checked code in repository and definitely end of comment is end of line:

```
048      * @var integer|timestamp|string
049      */
050     protected $created;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was the end of line character (\r\n), after changing to \n problem solved :)

Comment: You can then mark your answer as such, it's absolutely legit.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
048      * @var integer|timestamp|string */
049      protected $created;
```

Comment: Please explain why that would help